# TextChange listener usage with single TextView

Tags: android

I am using a addTextChangedListener that waits for user input from a textView as part of a simple quiz app.

I am using a single activity for all of the questions - updating the UI whenever the user proceeds to the next question. The problem i am having is that the listener is picking up events from all of the questions due to the same textView being used. Does anyone know any methods of making the listener only listen for events from the text view on the current question?

```
//Listener added in onCreate()
textViewLetter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
textViewLetter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            Toast t = Toast.makeText(Introduction.this, "Changed" Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }
    });
```

//Methods from which the UI is updated - lessonNo is the current question that the user is on.

```
public void questionOne(int lessonNo)
  {
    resetText();
    objective.setText(questions.get(lessonNo).getObjective());
}

public void questionTwo(int lessonNo)
{
    resetText();
    objective.setText(questions.get(lessonNo).getObjective());
}
```

Comment: If it's always using the same TextView, what are the other TextViews that are generating these events? Shouldn't there be just one?

Comment: I am using the one textView for all of the answers - the user is free to proceed to the next question or return to the previous one all of which are in the same activity and use the same textView. When ever the user proceeds/returns then the textView changes and the event gets triggered.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what you would want - the user tries to go to the next question, at which time the `afterTextChanged` event fires.  I don't see the problem.

Comment: His problem is he keeps adding a new TextWatcher each time he loads a new question (which I'm assuming is all happening within a single Activity). So the solution would be to keep a reference to the TextWatcher in your Activity class and ensure that you call textViewLetter.removeTextChangedListener(yourTextWatcherObject) before loading the next question

Comment: Excuse me, but this is a very crazy idea to wrap the logic of the app inside standart textView text change listener. Do not work this way.

Comment: @Vyacheslav I am a beginner and unsure how to structure this type of problem, please excuse of lack of knowledge.

Comment: What does resetText() do ? What do you mean with "the listener is pickung up events from all questions" ? What does exactly happen ?

Comment: @Jason Saruulo. The user can navigate through each 'stage' in the quiz. When the user navigates to a different question then the reset text clears the activity of the text - i am using the same text views for each question and just updating them depending on what question the user is on. Because i am using the same text view for all of the stages that means that when the user enters an answer and then changes questions the text gets reset (cleared) and the textwatcher picks up on this and the event is triggered.

Comment: Okay, so everything works as aspected right ? Resetting the text in the TextView fires one event and the second event is fired when setting the new text ?
Where is the point in resetting the text ? If you call #setText() on the TextView the text which was in the TextView before is cleared anyway ?
Why do you have a TextChangedListener assigned to the TextVIew ? What is the purpose of it ? I am a bit confused because a TextView is normally not taking input of an user is it ?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you **add** a listener to the `TextView`, not setting it.
If you call the `addTextChangeListener` more than once, you will have multiple listeners that will be triggred upon event.

When you need to load a new question, update the view rather than recreate it. Make sure all your initializing are done in `onCreate`, including setting listeners to your views.

When the user has to get the next question, update the `TextView`s with `setText` only (and the rest of the views)

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not use listener if directly do not what to catch the events.
In your case you can pure do this:

```
textViewLetter.setText("some data");
  Toast.makeText(this, "Changed" Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```